# Delete Files having space in names through iteration

Tags: unix

I have some unix code to delete some files, but some of these files contains spaces(one or two) in their names. So iterating and deleting is not working. Could anybody help me?
Code:

for file_name in `ls temp_for* | grep "temp_for_...\.lst"`
do

```
if [ -f $file_name ]
then
    echo '$file_name'
    rm "$file_name"
fi
```

done

files:
temp_for_ 1 .lst,
temp_for_ SI.lst,
temp_for_f S.lst

Answer (score 2):

Use [read](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read) to read whole lines:

```
ls ... | grep  ... | while read i 
do rm "$i"
done
```

Or use [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

```
find . -name '...' -exec rm {} \;
```

Or use find with [xargs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs):

```
find . -name '...' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Comment: Better use `find`, as filenames may contain newlines as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the filename in single quotes then it will escape spaces and special characters. Also you can use the backslash to escape spaces and other characters.

Example 1:

`'Filename with spaces'

Example 2:

Filename\ with\ spaces

Answer (score 0):

Enclose `$filename` in quotes , like so:

```
if [ -f "$file_name" ]
```